# Getting values from class tag with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: html, class, html-agility-pack

I'm having this code (see bellow) and I want to get the values 'Day.1' and 'Day.2' from it.

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();  
doc.LoadHtml("<div class=\"large-10 columns\"><div class=\"box\"><div class=\"table-header\">Day.1</div></div></div>" +
             "<div class=\"large-10 columns\"><div class=\"box\"><div class=\"table-header\">Day.2</div></div></div>");

var classes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class=\"large-10 columns\"]");
foreach (var item in classes)
{
    var str = item.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class=\"box\"]//div[@class=\"table-header\"]");
    Output += "Test: " + str.InnerText.Split('.')[1] + "\n";   
}
```

With this code the Output is:

```
Test: 1
Test: 1
```

Why the variable 'str' is getting the value from first 'table-header' class both times?

Comment: why don't you go straight for the `div[@class=\"table-header\"]` nodes?

Comment: you are using double `//` when you only need a single one `/`

Comment: because I need only them 2 values and 'table-header' can be found in other parts in HTML code..

Comment: then why don't you just use the full path?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
 doc.LoadHtml("<div class=\"large-10 columns\"><div class=\"box\"><div class=\"table-header\">Day.1</div></div></div>" +
                     "<div class=\"large-10 columns\"><div class=\"box\"><div class=\"table-header\">Day.2</div></div></div>");

        var classes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class=\"large-10 columns\"]/div[@class=\"box\"]/div[@class=\"table-header\"]");
        foreach (var item in classes)
        {
            var str = item.InnerText;
            Output += "Test: " + str.Split('.')[1] + "\n";
        }
```